# Unexpected behaviour of UIView.convert(_ point:to:)

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

I am trying to convert some view centers' to be able to draw a line between those `CGPoint`s.

However those points are perfectly aligned vertically, `convert` method returns unexpected values. Clearly I do miss something and could not figure out. Here I am asking :)

I quickly setup this code recreating the issue:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private lazy var backgroundView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var firstView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var secondView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var firstSubview: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemMint
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var secondSubview: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(backgroundView)
        
        backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        backgroundView.addSubview(firstView)
        backgroundView.addSubview(secondView)
        
        firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        firstView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        firstView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        secondView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        secondView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        secondView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        firstView.addSubview(firstSubview)
        
        firstSubview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        firstSubview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        firstSubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        firstSubview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        firstSubview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        secondView.addSubview(secondSubview)
        
        secondSubview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        secondSubview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        secondSubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        secondSubview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        secondSubview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
                
        let firstCenter1 = firstSubview.convert(firstSubview.center, to: view)
        let secondCenter1 = secondSubview.convert(secondSubview.center, to: view)
        
        print(firstCenter1, secondCenter1)
    }
}
```

The print results as `(45.0, 84.0) (55.0, 134.0)`, however, as I would expect, I should print out `(45.0, 84.0) (45.0, 134.0)`. Because the relative `center.x` of the `secondSubview` is literally `45.0` just as `firstSubview`.

I mixed and matched `convert`'s parameters and receiver but no luck. Even if I got `center.x`, then `center.y` gives the wrong value.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`center`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center) property returns a point in the *parent's* coordinate system.

> The center point is specified in points in the coordinate system of its superview. Setting this property updates the origin of the rectangle in the `frame` property appropriately.

Therefore, you should not call `convert` on the subviews. You should call it on `firstView` and `secondView`:

```
let firstCenter1 = firstView.convert(firstSubview.center, to: view)
let secondCenter1 = secondView.convert(secondSubview.center, to: view)
```